# Puppeteer: Network.setCookie returns invalid string param

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm learning to use the [CDPSession class](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession) in Puppeteer, but I'm having trouble with using the method parameters of the dev tools protocol.

[Dev Tools Network](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network)

The `Network.setCookie` section of the Dev tools docs show the params for setting the `name` cookie are: `name string`, but when I do this it returns an error: `Error: Protocol error (Network.setCookie): Invalid parameters value: string value expected`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send('Network.enable');
    const setCookie = await client.send('Network.setCookie', {
        name: 'mycookie'
    });

    console.log("Set Cookie: " + setCookie.success);
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await browser.close();
});
```

Comment: The answer was simple. I also needed to set the `value` and `url` or `domain` params. `const setCookie = await client.send('Network.setCookie', {
  name: 'mycookie',
  value: 'Hello',
  domain: 'https://example.com'
});`

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment! [Answering your own question is encouraged on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple. I also needed to set the value and url or domain params.

```
const setCookie = await client.send ( 'Network.setCookie', { 
    name: 'mycookie', value: 'Hello', domain: 'https://example.com' 
});
```

Comment: We could also set the cookie using await page.setCookie(cookie)